# Need to confirm my understanding of Servlet vs RESTful webpage's difference

Tags: javascript, html, rest, servlets

Is below understanding correct about RESTFulness?

Servlet webpages, e.g. Jsp, assembles a single HTML file at serverside, and then pass this SINGLE html document to user.

RESTful webpages (I mean, webpages developed in RESTful style), assembles the complete HTML document at user-side, with each piece of information retrieved from separate web-service uri's.

e.g. Consider a webpage to display name card of a person:
It shows:
person's name
person's profession
person's gender

In servlet webpage, given a person's ID to request, the backend server gather's the requested person's name, profession, and gender from DB, assemble them into a HTML file. And serve this HTML file to user.

In RESTful webpage, there is a JS function retrieving the person's name using URI#1, and render it to corresponding place on webpage DOM; retrieves the person's profession from URI#2, then render; then gender from URI#3.

(In reality, the resource might be in the form of a SINGLE person json object. Here just separate them for illustration purpose.)

Answer (score 1):

No. "Servlet webpages" only means that [Java Servlets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) are on the serverside. ["RESTful"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) only means that the serverside app has a modular structure where URLs correspond to resources, which are manipulated by selecting different HTTP verbs. The distinction that you are trying for is that between a [single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) and (for lack of a better word) classic web pages. You can implement a single-page application without adhering to REST, if you want to; and you can implement a RESTful application using Java Servlets, as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That is some good clarification between their definitions. But what I am trying to understand was to grab the differences between their philosophies.

Comment: There seems to be many forms of definition of RESTful-ness all over the internet. But still many people ask what it really means. (no kidding. I has been doing google searching and find many pages with this question.) I agree that JSP can also be made RESTful. But down to the gist of these two paradigm, what practice are considered RESTful conforming, which are considered as old-style Servlet?

Comment: And again I can only say that your question doesn't make sense - it's like asking what is the difference between baked desserts and chocolate ones. RESTful is that which conforms to REST; Servlet app is that which is implemented using interface defined in JSR-315. They are not on opposing sides of a spectrum.